# Custom Validation in silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, validation, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I create a site with Silverlight and I use custom validation when registering users. I want to prevent the registration of two users with the same username. I use `Entity Framework` and `WCF RIA`.
But when I insert the same username as a previously registered user, no error is displayed in my page. Why?

This is my code:

```
//this code is for domain service MetaData

[CustomValidation(typeof(UserExistValidation),"UserNotExist")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "username is required!")]
public string username { get;set; }
```

And my validator:

```
public class UserExistValidation
{
    public static ValidationResult UserNotExist(string username)
    {
        JobDBEntities myDB = new JobDBEntities();
        var query = (from u in myDB.tblUsers where u.username == username select new { u.username }).SingleOrDefault();
        if (query == null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else return new ValidationResult("this usename is existed!");
    }
}
```

and this is my xaml code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=username,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" x:Name="txtusername"/>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add `ValidatesOnExceptions=True` to your `Binding`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="UserNameInputElement"
       Text="{Binding Path=username, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

This should produce a red fly-out on validation errors.

[Edit]
I can see you never raise a `PropertyChanged` event, this might prevent the validation error propagation (just a vague thought, I had a similar problem not long ago).
Does it solve your problem if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and add:

```
public string username {
    get { return m_username; }
    set { m_username = value; RaiseUsernameChanged(); } }

private string m_username;

private void RaiseUsernameChanged()
{
    var h = PropertyChanged;
    if (h!=null) h(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("username"));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: i add this but my page does not change

Comment: @user3472324: What does your binding look like? Best thing would be you edit your question and provide the xaml part where the username binding can be seen.

Comment: i use domainservice.metadata for display errors.should i implement a class such as "newuser" that using validation errors on this in the my server project?

Comment: @user3472324: I added a part about `INotifyPropertyChanged` to my answer, does this solve your problem?